# Best way to create grid of divs?

Tags: css

I'm making a friends list script for an online browser game I play. I have 4 divs I need within the wrapper: 1) List of friends, 2) Add Friend, 3) Friend requests, 4) Chat. I figured out how to get the first two, but I need advice adding the rest. Here's what I have so far and what I want to add:

[image: div]

What would be the best way to add the two divs on the right? Should I make some sort of table of the 4 divs?

My css for the two divs both look something like this:

```
  position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 2%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
```

If anyone can give me insight on a good way to accomplish this setup I'd greatly appreciate it. Here's a fiddle of the basic outline I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/kfupd6hb/1/

Comment: I suggest bootstrap for designing grids,  you can make a demo grid in no time , Go to this    http://shoelace.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use float:left; attribute of css.
I've updated ur fiddle..
Somehow i'm unable to create a link here that's why providing link in comment.

Comment: updated fiddle again with more div to give u proper insight.https://jsfiddle.net/abhishekpanjabi/kfupd6hb/5/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `display:inline-block;` to get the `<div>`'s side by side, you can make a really perfect grid with that property.